# Flash and ASP.NET MVC to post data to server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, flash

what design approach would you take for security and scalability (and perhaps level of effort) when posting an ASP.NET MVC HTML form that also has a Flash component, as described in the scenario below?

I have a scenario where there's an ASP.NET MVC site, and a page that requires user authentication & authorization to access (using ASP.NET forms authentication). On that page there's an HTML form. The form also has a Flash component. The form has a few text fields, and the Flash component has binary data that needs to get submitted to the server in tandem with the HTML form fields. When the user hits the submit button on the HTML form, the form contents and binary data from the Flash need to get submitted as part of one atomic unit, so to speak.

I know that I can use HTML / Flash JavaScript bridging to post the form either through JavaScript, or through the Flash component. I could even do both, perhaps posting the binary data from the Flash component when the user clicks submit, and then posting the HTML form content following that.

From your experience, what approach would be the path of least resistance to post the form with? Considering the user authentication and authorization part, I imagine that Flash would higher effort than HTML. What about the user authentication aspect? If the page posted from Flash to the server, would Flash also have to authenticate the user, in addition to the standard HTML authentication form?

My Flash binary data should not typically be greater than 300KB, often less...any opinions / insights are greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
I also vaguely remember that with Flash 10.1, ExternalInterface seemed to not work right when transferring binary data to JavaScript, am I mistaken with that, and that you can easily transfer 300KB or more of binary data from Flash to a JavaScript variable that is then posted to the server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's one way of doing it:

1. Make your flash component call a javascript function through [ExternalInterface.call()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#call%28%29).
2. Make the called javascript function change a hidden field inside the form.
3. When the form is posted, the hidden field will send the desired value to the server.

I guess this is also the safest way - since the Flash component will **not** communicate with the server. Everything you need is a standard, non-AJAX form post.

**Edit**

Sorry, I guess I should have paid more attention... If there is too much data being sent from the flash component, maybe you should post it directly to the server.

Still, you could use ExternalInterface to synchronize the whole process. Make Flash call a server-side method (I would use [FluorineFX](http://fluorinefx.net/) for that, but your opinion may vary). Then .NET will return an ID, meaning it has received and saved the binary data for future use. Then call ExternalInterface to set that ID to a hidden field. After that, when the HTML is posted to the server, the server-side action method just need to retrieve the binary data using the posted ID...

The problem here is that you will end up with some binary data that will never be associated to any form post... But that's OK I guess, just run some "garbage-collector" script from time to time.

About the authentication issue: FluorineFX does implement [.NET authentication](http://fluorinefx.com/docs/fluorine/authentication.html), and it is able to retrieve the current logged in user. Of course, there are some [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680865/old-user-credentials-in-fluorinefx-after-resetting-a-session).

Comment: Thanks rsenna, I understand that approach, and the details of how to do it. Have you tried using ExternalInterface to pass binary data to JavaScript? I haven't had much luck with that.

Comment: @Shan Plourde: Hm got it. I had to do something like that (it was a small user drawn image in my case). What we did was encoding that image into a string, and using a reverse algorithm at the server side. Not exactly pretty, but it has worked just fine. I don't know if that approach would work with your case though. Maybe you will need distinct posts after all... :-/

Comment: Thanks for the design ideas, I will look into those. Any opinion on the benefits/drawbacks of FlourineFX versus simply calling WCF services from a Flash client?

Comment: @Shan Plourde: In fact I've never used WCF for that, so I'll not be able to compare. I suppose Fluorine is faster - you may use Flash Remoting or JSON-RPC for the communication, which is much lighter than SOAP, for instance.

Comment: Ok, I may go with the SOAP or REST approach to begin, since the service will also be called long term with different clients.